# Where are saves for The Last Nurse Joy located?

Tags: the-last-nurse-joy, save-location

Where are save files stored for the Pokemon fangame [*The Last Nurse Joy*](https://reliccastle.com/the-last-nurse-joy/) stored? I want to make a backup save, but the game only has one save slot.